# How to keep flatten JSON data regardless of level of nesting it is without specifying the levels in record path?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON tree that looks like this:

```
└─  (array)
   └─  (object)
      ├─ "site" (string)
      ├─ "title" (string)
      ├─ "child" (array)
      │  └─  (object)
      │     ├─ "type" (string)
      │     ├─ "value" (string)
      │     ├─ "child" (array)
      │     │  └─  (object)
      │     │     ├─ "type" (string)
      │     │     ├─ "value" (string)
      │     │     ├─ "child" (array)
      │     │     │  └─  (object)
      │     │     │     ├─ "type" (string)
      │     │     │     ├─ "key" (string)
      │     │     │     ├─ "id" (string)
      │     │     │     └─ "value" (string)
      │     │     ├─ "id" (string)
      │     │     └─ "key" (string)
      │     ├─ "id" (string)
      │     └─ "key" (string)
      ├─ "featured_image_url" (string)
      ├─ "id" (string)
      └─ "key" (string)
```

I think this represents the above data:

```
data = [{"site": "example", "title": "Example Site", "child": [{"type": "text", "value": "This is some text.", "child": [{"type": "image", "value": "image.jpg", "child": [{"type": "link", "key": "link1", "id": "link1", "value": "Link 1"}], "id": "text1", "key": "text1"}, {"type": "image", "value": "image2.jpg", "child": [{"type": "link", "key": "link2", "id": "link2", "value": "Link 2"}], "id": "text2", "key": "text2"}], "id": "root", "key": "root"}, {"featured_image_url": "featured_image.jpg", "id": "root2", "key": "root2"}]}]
```

My goal is too extract all data in every `child` array regardless of the level of nesting. `child` is list of dictionary objects.

I have tried using `pd.json_normalize` with record path set to `child` per level, but at some point the dataframe does not have records for every record in the `child` column. Some values are `nan` some are empty lists.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['child', 'child', 'child'],
                       meta=['site', 'title', 'featured_image_url',
                             'id', 'key','child'],
                       meta_prefix='_')
```

The `df.child` from the above code looks like this:

```
                       child
0                                                    NaN
1      [{'type': 'HTML', 'key': '77100c3f-760d-452a-a...
2      [{'type': 'HTML', 'key': '6fce8911-7e46-42e5-b...
3      []
```

Is there anyway I can extract all data from every `child` array regardless of nesting for  data for `type`, `key`, `id`, `value` into a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

data = [{"site": "example", "title": "Example Site", "child": [{"type": "text", "value": "This is some text.", "child": [{"type": "image", "value": "image.jpg", "child": [{"type": "link", "key": "link1", "id": "link1", "value": "Link 1"}], "id": "text1", "key": "text1"}, {"type": "image", "value": "image2.jpg", "child": [{"type": "link", "key": "link2", "id": "link2", "value": "Link 2"}], "id": "text2", "key": "text2"}], "id": "root", "key": "root"}, {"featured_image_url": "featured_image.jpg", "id": "root2", "key": "root2"}]}]

items = data
result = []
for i in items:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        items.extend(i)
    elif isinstance(i, dict):
        entry = {k:v for k, v in i.items() if isinstance(v, str)}
        result.append(entry)
        child = i.pop("child", None)
        if child is not None:
            items.extend(child)

pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(result)
```

### Output

```
[   {'site': 'example', 'title': 'Example Site'},
    {   'id': 'root',
        'key': 'root',
        'type': 'text',
        'value': 'This is some text.'},
    {'featured_image_url': 'featured_image.jpg', 'id': 'root2', 'key': 'root2'},
    {'id': 'text1', 'key': 'text1', 'type': 'image', 'value': 'image.jpg'},
    {'id': 'text2', 'key': 'text2', 'type': 'image', 'value': 'image2.jpg'},
    {'id': 'link1', 'key': 'link1', 'type': 'link', 'value': 'Link 1'},
    {'id': 'link2', 'key': 'link2', 'type': 'link', 'value': 'Link 2'}]
```

You can now prepare/modify `result`, so that it fits into a pandas DataFrame.